# gwt - trigger recalculation of 100% width

Tags: events, firefox, google-chrome, gwt, resize

I have a ScrollPanel in which 
I have a FlexTable with two columns and a dynamic number of rows.
The first column only contains Labels, the second various widgets.

Some of those widgets in the second column are manually layed out triggered by a ResizeEvent.
When one of those manually resizing widget is present, and the browserwindow gets resized to a smaller size, then vertical scrollbars will apear and allow to scroll the area in the size that was previously present. When I resize a second time then the width of the first resize-step will be the new minimum size that the ScrollPanel will represent.

This problem only exists for firefox and chrome, IE does work as expected.

I tried to manually call my resize procedure twice with the same ResizeEvent but that doesn't help. I also tried to fire the ResizeEvent on the ScrollPanel after my widgets have completed their manual resize procedure, also had no effect on this problem.

I cannot disable the vertical scrollbar completly. Some of the widgets have a minimal width, and if the browser gets smaller then the biggest minimal width + the width of the label column than the scrollbar is necessary.

Comment: "IE does work as expected"  If I had a dollar for every time I heard that I'd be..... poor.